# Python. Передача переменных методов между классами

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyside

```
class MainWnd(QMainWindow, mainGui.Ui_RecistMainWindow):

   def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWnd, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.exitApp)
        self.actionNew_subject.triggered.connect(self.newsubj_clicked)
        self.baseline_btn.clicked.connect(self.baseline_clicked)

    def newsubj_clicked(self, parent=None):
        dialog = NewSubject()
        dialog.exec_()
        self.id_label.setText(dialog.createid_lineedit.text())
        self.baseline_btn.setEnabled(True)

    def baseline_clicked(self):
        dialogbs = BaseLine()
        dialogbs.exec_()

    def exitApp(self):
        sys.exit(0)

class NewSubject(QDialog, newidGui.Ui_newSubjId):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, idparam=None):
        super(NewSubject, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.createid_lineedit.setFocus()

class BaseLine(QDialog, baselineGui.Ui_BaseLine):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(BaseLine, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)





def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainWnd()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Вопрос таков:

Програмка состоит из 3х окошек пока что.
Запускаем главный файл, открывается MainWnd(наше главное окошко), в нем кликаем создать новый айди - открывается второе окошко NewSubject. Здесь вводим значение айди. Это значение нужно передать в основное окно как лейбл. Далее запускаем третье окно BaseLine и в нем тоже должна быть лейба, которую мы передали со второго окна.

Так вот я не могу передать это значение со второго окна в третье с такой последовательностью их запуска.
Подскажите, как это можно сделать или что нужно изменить?

Comment: Разве это `self.id_label.setText(dialog.createid_lineedit.text())` не работает? Вызвали тот диалог, заполнили в нем значения, после его закрытия достали нужные значения

Comment: для основоного окна работает. как передать это значение в третье окно не пойму.self.id_label.setText(dialog.createid_lineedit.text()) -передает ID введенный новый в главное окно.  как передать это значение в третье окно?

Comment: сохранить значение в основном окне, при открытии третьего окна передать значение в него, например, в конструкторе диалога передать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил пример передачи значения в третье окно, которое было полученное из второго:

```
class MainWnd(QMainWindow, mainGui.Ui_RecistMainWindow):
   def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWnd, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.exitApp)
        self.actionNew_subject.triggered.connect(self.newsubj_clicked)
        self.baseline_btn.clicked.connect(self.baseline_clicked)

    def newsubj_clicked(self, parent=None):
        dialog = NewSubject()
        dialog.exec_()
        self.id_label.setText(dialog.createid_lineedit.text())
        self.baseline_btn.setEnabled(True)

    def baseline_clicked(self):
        dialogbs = BaseLine(self.id_label.text())
        dialogbs.exec_()

    def exitApp(self):
        sys.exit(0)


class NewSubject(QDialog, newidGui.Ui_newSubjId):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, idparam=None):
        super(NewSubject, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.createid_lineedit.setFocus()


class BaseLine(QDialog, baselineGui.Ui_BaseLine):
    def __init__(self, id_value, parent=None):
        super(BaseLine, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        print(id_value)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainWnd()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Все верно. работает. Спасибо.